# if condition in aspx markup tag

Tags: asp.net, webforms, aspxgridview

How do I set the value of primaryKey attribute in a gridview aspx markup bases on condition?

```
<% 
string val=string.Empty;
if(Id=1){
%>
val="red";
<% else { %>
val="blue";
<%} %>

<GridView runat="server" id="someid" PrimaryKey=val />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have issues, you need to fix that.

**Issue 1**

`if(Id=1){` Not correct , it should be if`(Id==1){`

**Issue 2:**

Propriety should not be `PrimaryKey` it should be `DataKeyNames`

**Issue 3:**

```
<GridView runat="server" id="someid" PrimaryKey=val />
```

It should be

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" id="someid"  />
```

Instead of using a variable and using that for setting, you can do it like following.

```
          <% 
                string val = string.Empty;
                if (Id == 1)
                {
                    someid.PrimaryKey = "red";
                }
                else
                {
                    someid.PrimaryKey = "blue";
                }
            %>
            <asp:GridView runat="server" id="someid" />
```